# How to receive data over wifi router in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, serial-port, wifi, router

Hi I'm doing a research on wireless networks. I'm not good at C#.  Normally, I  use serial I/O to send data from Jennic JN5139's UART to PC via USB.  I want to connect JN5139's UART output to a wireless router via a USB to Ethernet adaptor.

How can I read data which is sent to the router, and then send the data from the router to a computer over Wi-Fi?  I don't even know where to start looking for a solution to this problem. Could anyone offer me a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over the router, you can intercept the traffic outbound from the computer to the router via your Ethernet device. You can then capture the wireless traffic inbound to the computer from the wireless router using WireShark and a supported wireless NIC. Take a look [here in the Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) for more detailed information on capture WLAN traffic and the caveats involved.

If you want to capture traffic programmatically with C# there are a number of frameworks available to you to use. [Consider SharpPCap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET).

Comment: Thank you for your concern.When I was searching I bump into with Wireshark but I need to read data programmitacally especially using C# because I need to make some calculations using received data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a serial port accessible over a network, you would need some sort of device server.  I can highly recommend those from [COMTROL](http://www.comtrol.com/devicemaster-freewire-wireless-device-servers/devicemaster-freewire) and [Digi](http://www.digi.com/products/serialservers/digiconnectwisp), but there are also many [cheaper versions](https://www.google.com/#q=serial+device+server&tbm=shop) out there.

Once the device is connected, it will be assigned an IP Address and Port.  You can then connect to the serial port across the network using the [`TcpClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a `Stream` in much the same way as a `SerialPort` class.

It also seems like Jennic has their own proprietary [JenNET to Ethernet bridge](http://www.jennic.com/products/protocol_stacks/jennet-ip).  They may be able to provide further support or direction.

Comment: I have Dlink 2360 does it do same job with your offers comtrol and digi. I think no. I will try to use router of JENNIC but still neeed to find a general solutions in case I need to add some non jennic devices to network.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan, no, the DLink 2306 is a wireless access point, it would not take the place of a computer when communicating with a serial port.